# Why doesn't my Android ViewModel's Room RxJava3 Flowable publish any result when my Activity is paused?

Tags: android-room, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel, rx-java3

I'm aware it's a complex question that cannot have a definite answer without posting a few hundreds of lines of code, which is why I'm looking for help through general ideas and pointers.

I have a Room `@Query` returning a RxJava3 `Flowable<List<...>>` which I subscribe to on RxJava thread `Schedulers.io()`, and observe from an activity-scoped `ViewModel` on RxJava thread `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`. The data is then stored in my ViewModel as `LiveData`, which plays better than RxJava when it comes to handle Android components' lifecycle.

The idea is to have a clean and immediate data update pattern, not to have to handle disposal and re-subscription separately on each activity or fragment lifecycle event such as `onPaused` and `onResumed`, and being updated in the background even when my activity is hidden in order to avoid that awful refresh lag when returning to my activity. I was pretty amazed at that design pattern. I still am, but I'm beginning to have doubts.

When starting another activity with the same design pattern, I do change a value and immediately get an updated `List<...>` from the other `ViewModel`. Different `Activity`, different `ViewModel`, same design, same database table. When returning to the first `Activity`, I find that the new data does never get updated: Room did not emit any update even though the data set has changed. I have to dispose and subscribe again in order to see the new data.

So my question is: any pointer on where the source of my problem might be?! Is there something rotten in the core of this design pattern? Something I misunderstood about all those things are supposed to work together? Is it just a mistake of mine due to some threading issue? Or should I fill a bug report for Room?

I tried to observe another non-Room RxJava3 observable from the `ViewModel` of my first `Activity`, and it does get updates when its data set is updated.

By the way, I also use Hilt in order to inject eveything as `@Singleton`.

Thank you for your time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week of headaches, I have finally stumbled upon a solution, which happens to be clean and elegant.

The issue was RxJava, which, I just learnt, is not supposed to seamlessly handle multiple subscriptions to the same `Observable`. The solution is supposedly to make use of the `publish()`, `connect()`, `refcount()` operators, or better use the shortcut `share()`. I tried every way I could think of, without success (it actually made it worse). I also tried to `subscribe()` to the Room `Flowable` from my repository and proxy it through a `BehaviorSubject`.

There was this weird `org.reactivestreams.Publisher` in Room's documentation, whose added value I wouldn't know, and whose origin wasn't even my familiar `io.reactivex.rxjava3`. It turns out it that was the solution. **Edit:** It turns out `Publisher` is an interface that `Flowable` happens to implement.

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:+'
```

**Dao.java**

```
@Query("...")
Flowable<List<...>> getFlowable();
```

**ViewModel.java**

```
public liveData;

@Inject
public ViewModel(@NonNull RoomDatabase roomDatabase) {
    liveData = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(roomDatabase.dao().getFlowable());
}
```

It seems too easy to be true, but as far as I can see it seems to work <s>perfectly</s> *better this way*.

**Edit:**
It turns out the root of this issue was a slight little bit more vicious than I thought. I assumed `@InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class)` in my dependency injection `@Module` was enough, but apparently a `@Singleton` annotation on each `@Provides` method is also required.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class)
public abstract class DependencyInjection
{
    @Provides
    @NonNull
    @Singleton // do not omit this
    public static DataDao provideDataDao(@NonNull RoomDatabase roomDatabase) {
        return roomDatabase.dataDao();
    }

    @Provides
    @NonNull
    @Singleton // do not omit this
    public static RoomDatabase provideRoomDatabase(@ApplicationContext Context applicationContext) {
        return
                BuildConfig.DEBUG ?
                        Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, RoomDatabase.class, "playground.db").fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build() :
                        Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, RoomDatabase.class, "playground.db").build() ;
    }
}
```